# How to download Microsoft VS 2015 build tools iso without being logged in

Tags: download, iso-image, visual-studio-2015

The old online installer of VS 2015 CPP Build Tools has been removed since the change here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/sha-1-signed-content-retired

But I still need it. There are download links available here: [https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20c%20%20%20build%20tools&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20c%20%20%20build%20tools&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads)

But it needs to be logged in.

I need to download it from a CI pipeline, in a Windows Server Core Dockerfile, so I can't login.

Is there any way to download it without being logged in?

Downloading directly from the website gives me a 403 : https://download.my.visualstudio.com/pr/mu_visual_cpp_build_tools_2015_update_3_x64_dvd_dfd9a39c.iso

Alternatively, if the license allows, I could host in a webserver, but I can't figure out if it's alright to serve this file on the web too.

Comment: Maybe you could manually create a derived Docker image with the tools installed and then use that in your CI pipelines. That way, some manual work wouldn’t hurt _that_ much.

Comment: What is your Windows version? What error are you getting? SHA1 only relates to websites, not to installations.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Microsoft Buid Tools installer" instead. That will take you to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

[image]

You don't need to be logged in to download this `.exe`

The resultant downloaded file is called `BuildTools_Full.exe`.

Comment: This is not the offline installer.

Comment: Noted, I've removed the "offline" bit. I believe it's a complete installer though.

Comment: Indeed, the file-name is `BuildTools_Full.exe`.

Comment: It gives "a setup package is either missing or damaged" since the tools it tries to download fails due to the SHA-1 deprecation, this is why it needs to be the offline installer.

Comment: "a setup package is either missing or damaged" implies there's a pre-requisite application missing, such as `.NET Framework 4.5` or higher.

Comment: yes, as I said on the question, see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/sha-1-signed-content-retired